# How to serve a docker content folder to my apache server?

Tags: docker

I have my server running apache on port 80 and a docker images running on that server as well.
I want to HTTP publish/map the content of /var/www/ from my docker to /var/www/docker on my real server

So when I run http://myserver/content it fetches the content on my docker /var/www

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what volumes are for. With a volume a path inside of the container is mounted/bound on a path outside of the container. This allows both domains to access the files in that file system subtree.

To do what you describe (have `/var/www/docker/` on the host be the same as `/var/www/` in the container) you would call docker like this:

`docker run [...] -v /var/www/docker:/var/www [image-name]`

Answer (score 0):

When you run your docker image, mount a volume by adding this flag:

```
docker run ... -v /var/www/docker:/var/www ... <Your image name>
```

This way, the contents of the `/var/www/docker` folder in your host will be available in the `/var/www` folder inside your container.